# How does nginx use steam tcp to forward real ip to mysql

Tags: mysql, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

nginx.conf

```
stream{
        server {
                listen 3308;
                proxy_pass localhost:3306;

                proxy_timeout 60s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        }
}
```

This configuration can correctly proxy to the mysql service, but the ip address connecting to mysql is **'localhost'**, not my real ip address. Because the mysql user set some IP can connect.If I want the real ip address to connect to the mysql service instead of localhost, how should I modify the configuration?

Comment: You cant, what you want is not possible. You allways see "localhost" in mysql since nginx creates the client socket to your mysql database. There is no way for Layer 4 to due such a thing. In HTTP (Layer 7) this works also only because the "X-FORWARDED-FOR" header.